# Is there another calendar with the equivalent of gregorians weeks?

Tags: time, calendar

In the gregorian calendar, we split the time in years, months, weeks and days.

A week is the total of seven days.

I was looking at the persan calendar, being one of the most precise known calendar. However, on wikipedia (french page), I cannot find any reference to an "equivalent" of gregorians weeks.

So, is there any other calendar that splits/split months into a unit of measurement we could consider the equivalent of gregorian weeks ?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean with "equivalent", may something like this  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry454?

Comment: The French Republican Calendar, actually used for a time in France... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_Republican_calendar  The weeks were 10 days each, called "décades".

Comment: Well I think that's an answer @GeraldEdgar !

Comment: While I was more looking for something as Gerald Edgar proposed, your proposition is also a valuable answer to me @user6530.

Comment: My comment converted to an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The French Republican Calendar, actually used for a time in France... [LINK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_Republican_calendar)
The weeks were 10 days each, called "décades".